# How to add margins to cell in LaTex

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, margins

I've been two days trying to add top and bottom margins to some cells in my latex table (the ones that have the more text). I couldn't find a solution. This is the code I have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabu}{|X[2]|X[10]|X[2]|X[7]|X|
X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{Id. number 1} & 
     number 1 & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Id. n2} & 
     number 2& 
     \rotatebox{90}{Esfuerzo p-d} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 1} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 2} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 3} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 4} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 5} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 6} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 7} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 8} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 9} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 10} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 11} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 12} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 13} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 14} & 
     \rotatebox{90}{Día 15}\\ 
     \hline
     \multirow[c]{6}{=}{COM-HU01} &
     \multirow[c]{6}{=}{This is a cell with a lot of information that have to be in a paragraph style in the table} &
    01-01 & Do some things also in a semi-pharagraph style &
    2 & & & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \cline{3-20}
 & & 01-02 & Some other things
    & 2 &  & 1 &  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \cline{3-20} 
 & & 01-03 & To do number three
    & 3 & & & & & & & & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \cline{3-20} 
 & & 01-04 & To do number four
    & 1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &   \\ \cline{3-20} 
 & & 01-05 & To do number five
    & 2 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ \cline{3-20} 
 & & 01-06 & Another semi pharagraph style cell 
    & 3 & & & & & & & & 1 & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.
PD: I would also appreciate if there's any way to vertically center all the cells

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant package? Could you please also clarify what "top and bottom margins" refers to? Do you want to add some vertical white space between teh text and the surrounding borders of the cells?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Are you set on using `tabu`? Or could you live with using another tabular environment?

Comment: @TivV: I'd guess the vertical alignment issue in this particular case is more related to the use of multirow.

Comment: @leandriis, Hi, thank you for helping me. Some cells are just too tight between the top line and the text, and between the bottom line and the text, yes

Comment: @VioletaGarcía: Thanks for the edit and the clarification. Could you please also add the document class you are currently using?

Comment: @leandriis it's an article in landscape

Comment: @VioletaGarcía: That makes sense. I already wonderes how such a wide table would fit into a portrait page. To get back to an earlier question of TivV: Do you have to use `tabu` or would using an alternative be fine for you as well? (Background: `tabu` is currently unmaintained and might cause undesired effects.)

Comment: @leandriis I don't care which table use. I used tabu because it was the first one I found to use with |X| columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion building upon `tabularx` for the `X` type colums, `makecell` for the rotated column headers, `cellspace` for the additional white space between text and horizontal line, `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}` to left align the contents of the newly defined `L` type columns and `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` to vertically center the contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Id. number 1}
    \renewcommand\cellrotangle{90}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|S{c}|S{L}|S{c}|L|*{16}{S{c}|}}
\hline
\rothead{Id. number 1} & 
     number 1 & 
     \rothead{Id. n2} & 
     number 2& 
     \rothead{Esfuerzo p-d} & 
     \rothead{Día 1} & 
     \rothead{Día 2} & 
     \rothead{Día 3} & 
     \rothead{Día 4} & 
     \rothead{Día 5} & 
     \rothead{Día 6} & 
     \rothead{Día 7} & 
     \rothead{Día 8} & 
     \rothead{Día 9} & 
     \rothead{Día 10} & 
     \rothead{Día 11} & 
     \rothead{Día 12} & 
     \rothead{Día 13} & 
     \rothead{Día 14} & 
     \rothead{Día 15}\\ 
     \hline
     \multirow[c]{12.5}{*}{\makecell{COM-\\HU01}} &
     \multirow[c]{12.5}{=}{This is a cell with a lot of information that have to be in a paragraph style in the table} &
    01-01 & Do some things also in a semi-pharagraph style &
    2 & & & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \cline{3-20}
 & & 01-02 & Some other things
    & 2 &  & 1 &  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \cline{3-20} 
 & & 01-03 & To do number three
    & 3 & & & & & & & & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \cline{3-20} 
 & & 01-04 & To do number four
    & 1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &   \\ \cline{3-20} 
 & & 01-05 & To do number five
    & 2 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ \cline{3-20} 
 & & 01-06 & Another semi pharagraph style cell 
    & 3 & & & & & & & & 1 & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seriously, I've been looking for this two entire days and you solved it in half an hour. Thank you so much

Comment: @VioletaGarcía: You're welcome. If you need some explanation on the code I used, please don't hesitate to ask.